Unable to complete a partial restore of our Azure DevOps database
We are in a situation where we need to restore some data from our backups.
We managed to restore the Tfs_Configuration and Tfs_DefaultCollection databases onto a test SQL server.
The production environment has many more collections, we have only restored the Configuration and DefaultCollection. I was expecting this should be sufficient to get it back online.
Now we are trying to get these collections online using a test server, so we can extract the required data and then destroy this test setup.
When running the tfsconfig remapdbs command we get the complaint it cannot find the other databases.
"TF246064: No database could be found for the following host: CollectionName2. The host has the following ID: [guid]. To fix this problem, use the TFSCOnfig RemapDBs command-line tool and make sure that you specify the SQL Server instance that contains this database."

I tried the tfsconfig collections /detach and /delete, but these were also not accepted because it cannot find the database.
Also the offlineDetach has not been succesfull yet.
I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to restore part of the collections.
Is there a command line i can run to unregister the collections? Or even make a database modification in Tfs_Configuration to ensure the other collections are no longer considered?
I have already tried to remove the rows from the Tbl_Database, but this resulted in other errors when running TfsConfig.
Once we extracted the data we need we plan to destroy these restored databases.

Based on the comments from Ziyang Liu-MSFT below, we have been able to resolve our problem of restoring a subset of the Azure DevOps Server databases.
In our scenario we were not able to detach the database before the backup, we had to use a backup copy from the weekly backup rotation.
It seems it is not possible to get this combination online, instead we had to use the OfflineDetach option to configure the collection database in the right state.
Steps we took to get the project collection online on a test server

Restore the AzureDevOps_Configuration and AzureDevOps_Collection database onto a test server
Run the tfsconfig remapDbs command with the /continue flag: tfsconfig remapDBs /DatabaseName:TESTHOSTSQL;AzureDevOps_Configuration /SQLInstances:TESTHOSTSQL /continue
Now that the Configuration and Collection database are correctly mapped to the new SQL Instance, we can continue with the OfflineDetach
Run the tfsconfig OfflineDetach command: tfsconfig offlineDetach /configurationDb:TESTHOSTSQL;AzureDevOps_Configuration /collectionDB:TESTHOSTSQL;AzureDevOps_DefaultCollection
Now the AzureDevOps_DefaultCollection is decoupled from the original Configuration database, we can now attach the DefaultCollection database to any other Azure DevOps deployment
In our case we setup a new Azure DevOps Server application server with a new AzureDevops_Collection database
Attach the decoupled collection into the Azure DevOps environment
It should now be online and accessible


If you only want to restore partial collections to a new server, just restoring Tfs_DefaultCollection databases is enough.
1. Detach the collection
Before you move a collection, first detach it from the deployment of Azure DevOps Server on which it is running.
2. Back up the collection database
After you have detached the collection, back up its database to move it to the other server. To perform this task, use the tools that are provided with SQL Server.

3. Move the collection database
As part of moving the collection, you must restore, copy, or otherwise move the collection database to an instance of SQL Server that is configured to support the deployment of Azure DevOps Server to which you're moving the collection.
4. Attach the collection
After you restore the collection database, you can attach the collection to the preferred deployment of Azure DevOps Server.
5. Configure the moved project collection
You can skip this procedure if you moved the collection in the same domain, and intend to use the same web application that previously supported the collection, and you want to allow access for the administrators of that collection to this deployment of Azure DevOps Server.
6. Configure projects
You can skip this procedure if you moved the collection in the same domain and you want to allow access for the users of projects in that collection to this deployment of Azure DevOps Server.
See the detailed info from Move a project collection.

Thank you for your reply. In our case, we are restoring from a backup, so i do not have the option to Detach the collection first.
Is there any workable solution instead of restoring all collections?

You can start from step3. Just restore Tfs_DefaultCollection DB and move it to your target server. Then attach the collection to your test server.

We tried that, the restored database is not showing up in the Attach collection dialog, what should we do to make it appear here?

Additionally, when trying we TFSConfig collections /attach, we run into the same issue as here
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-attach-un-detached-database-into-tfs2015/922036
Are you sure this method is supported?

So, you mean that you haven't detached the collection before backup? If so, you can't just restore Tfs_DefaultCollection DB. For error "TF246064: No database could be found for the following host...", try to add a /Continue flag in your TfsConfig remapDBs command and check if it helps.

thanks we will try that. We just picked the backups from the weekly TFS Backups that were made using the TFS Admin console

we got it to work, see my solution post above

Thanks for your detailed updates. It would be helpful for others who may have the same issue.
